# Unable to pass three variables to another page in url using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass three variables to another page in url using php but am not able to pass three variables.
I'm able to pass two variables to another page in url.
 
Please help me.

Code

```
header("location: designer_edit.php?success=$success&reg_id=".$param_reg_id);
```

Comment: `header("location: designer_edit.php?success=$success&reg_id=".$param_reg_id."&param3=".$param_3);`?

Comment: Can you show examples of the values you are trying to pass and describe the problem that you are having.

Comment: It works. Thank you  @Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can just append the third parameter to the location string. For example:

```
header("location: designer_edit.php?success=$success&reg_id=".
       $param_reg_id.
       "&param3=".$param_3);
```

Note that if the variables can contain special characters, you should pass them through [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) first:

```
header("location: designer_edit.php?" .
       "success=" . urlencode($success) .
       "&reg_id=" . urlencode($param_reg_id).
       "&param3=" . urlencode($param_3));
```